# MySQL Inserting with single quotes using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a code to insert into mysql database. Which is

schname is something like = St. Thame's College

```
$schname = $_GET['schname'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO `school` (id, schname, place) VALUES (' ',  $schname, 'place',)";
```

But after the 's in $schname the query wont run. Can I get to know how to solve that, as all most all school names have 's after their name.

Comment: Not an answer but i guess you have a typo error too last comma in your query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$schname = addslashes($_GET['schname']);
```

Use variable with addslashes function

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but either your code and op code's are vulnerable to mysql injections

Comment: This code will not work; a string such as `St. Thame's College` will need to be escaped and quoted in single quotes.

Comment: will have to use values (' ','$schname','place') after doing addslashes as answered by @nikul

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'s College , 'UK'  at line 1 .. i got this error

Comment: If you will use addslashes("St. Thame's College").  it will take that variable as  "St. Thame\'s College".

Comment: It worked. Thank You. @Fabio what do you mean these are vulnerable to mysql injections?

Comment: @ruch1234 that's what i meant, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

Need to wrap the variable in quotes.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$schname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['schname']);
$sql= "INSERT INTO `school` (id, schname, place) VALUES (' ', '$schname', 'place')";

$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Ref. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php